# custom view with height based on own width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I am currently developing an Android App for Tablets, landscape mode only.
My question:
How can I display a View with a height based on the width?
A LinearLayout holds my View so that I can use the weight attribute.
My height always has to be 1/3 of my width while the width always has to be a specific percentage of the parent, in this case 80%(sum weight is set to 1, weight is 0.8) How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the onMeasure() method of view and customize this functionality. Alternatively you can use the library

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout